# C++ ofstream write does not work under Windows. Works fine under Linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, binary, ofstream

The code below does not work under Windows and GNU C++, VS10,VS12, Intel C++ 14.0. The code below does work under Linux and GNU C++ 4.7, 4.8, Intel C++ 14, Open64 5.0.Replacing DIMEN with DIMEN-256 in the inner test for-loop ... works!? Any idea?

```
//============================//
// Read and Write binary file //
// using buffers              //
//============================//

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  // 1. variables and parameters

  const long int DIMEN = static_cast<long int>(pow(10.0,8.0));
  const long int I_DO_MAX = 100;
  const string fileName = "my_file.bin";
  ofstream fileOUT;
  ifstream fileIN;
  double* myArrayAlpha = new double [DIMEN];
  double* myArrayBeta = new double [DIMEN];
  long int i;
  long int j;

  // 2. build the array with some data

  cout << " 1 --> Build the array with some data" << endl;

  for (i = 0; i < DIMEN; i++)
  { myArrayAlpha[i] = static_cast<double>(i); }

  for (i = 0; i < I_DO_MAX; i++)
  {
    // 3. open the file stream

    cout << "-------------->>> " << i << endl;
    cout << " 2 --> Open the file stream" << endl;

    fileOUT.open(fileName.c_str(), ios::out | ios::binary | ios::trunc);
    fileIN.open(fileName.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary); 

    // 4. test if the file stream is opened 

    cout << " 3 --> Test if the file stream is opened with success" << endl;

    if (!fileOUT.is_open())
    { cout << "Error! The output file stream is not opened. Exit." 
           << endl; return -1; }

    if (!fileIN.is_open())
    { cout << "Error! The input file stream is not opened. Exit." 
           << endl; return -1; }

    // 5. write the contents of myArrayAlpha[] to a file

    cout << " 4 --> Write and then Read to the file" << endl;

    fileIN.seekg(0, fileIN.beg);
    fileOUT.seekp(0);

    fileOUT.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&myArrayAlpha[0]), 
                  DIMEN * sizeof(double));
    fileIN.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&myArrayBeta[0]), 
                DIMEN * sizeof(double));

    // 6. test that I am writting and reading correctly

    for (j = 0; j < DIMEN; j++) // replace DIMEN 
    {                           // with DIMEN-256 to work under Windows
      if (myArrayAlpha[j] != myArrayBeta[j])
      { cout << myArrayAlpha[j] << endl;
        cout << myArrayBeta[j] << endl;
        cout << "j = " << j << endl;
        cout << "Error!"; return -1; }
    }

    cout << " 5 --> Read and Write with success" << endl;
    cout << " 6 --> Close the I/O streams" << endl;

    // 7. close the file stream

    fileIN.close();
    fileOUT.close();
  }

  // 8. free up the RAM

  delete [] myArrayAlpha;
  delete [] myArrayBeta;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This might be a case of Undefined Behavior.

Comment: What means "does not work" ?

Comment: It might be that you're performing a read directly after performing a write to the same file without synchronizing the two streams. Try adding `fileOUT << std::flush` after the `write()` call.

Comment: Does not write DIMEN elements but DIMEN-256. So when I am testing using the inner for loop from (j = 0; j < DIMEN; j++) breaks.

Comment: What do you mean by "it breaks"? Have you tried doing `fileOUT << std::flush; fileIN.sync()` before the next `read()`?

Comment: fileOUT << flush; I added that after the fileOUT.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&myArrayAlpha[0]), DIMEN * sizeof(double)); and WORKS! 0x499602D2 THANKS!

Comment: Okay great! Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your data is not being flushed to the external sequence after the `write` call, so it is still positioned in the internal buffer. Add this line after `write()`:

```
fileOUT << std::flush;
```

Comment: 0x499602D2 Thanks! Adding fileOUT << std::flush; resolved the issue under Windows and VS10, VS12, Intel C++ 13.0.